# floating point multiply problem in verilog

Tags: architecture, floating-point, verilog, multiplication, hdl

For a given project I encountered with *floating point multiplication* in ***verilog***. So I used from IP cores of Xilinx in ISE 14.7
with following configurations for floating point IP core GUI:

- Multiply
- Single (Exponent width : 8 bit, fraction width : 24)
- No usage (in family optimization)
- maximum latency (which is here 8 clock cycles)

so when I give the following inputs in ieee 754 format

```
A = 0_0111111_000000000000000000000000 (which is one)

B = 0_0111111_000000000000000000000000
```

the result after 8 clock cycles is :

```
0_0111110_100000000000000000000000
```

my question is why the result is not one in ieee 754 format?
who is wrong?

Comment: Your assertion that `A` is `1` isn't correct. It actually is `0.5`. And the result decodes as `0.25` which is the correct answer. See below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your first number decodes:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01111110 00000000000000000000000
             Hex: 3F00 0000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -1 (Stored: 126, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1p-1
           Value: +0.5 (NORMAL)
```

So, its value is `0.5`, not `1` as you claimed.

This is how the product decodes:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01111101 00000000000000000000000
             Hex: 3E80 0000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -2 (Stored: 125, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1p-2
           Value: +0.25 (NORMAL)
```

So, it's `0.25`. And that is correct since `0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25` indeed.

If you want to test multiplying `1 * 1 = 1` use the following encoding:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01111111 00000000000000000000000
             Hex: 3F80 0000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 0 (Stored: 127, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1p0
           Value: +1.0 (NORMAL)
```

i.e., `0_01111111_00000000000000000000000` which is how the number `1.0` is encoded as an 32 bit single-precision IEEE754 floating point value. Note in particular that the exponent is 8-bits, which seems to be the source of the issue in your original encoding where you have 7 bits.